# Yii Error while accessing rights module

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I get the following error while accessing the rights module,

```
 array_map() [<a href='function.array-map'>function.array-map</a>]: Argument #2 should be an array
```

i have enabled the rights module by adding proper configuration settings in the main.php file

Please can somebody help me out in fixing this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though your rights are not correctly defined within the controller.

So when the function goes through what would normally be after position `[1]` which is `actions` (since `expression`, `roles` and `message` all go into a different condition as you can see) allowed on the controller is it finding no array there.

I cannot be more specific about what is really happening without seeing your code but I suspects you have probably tried:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>'*',
            'users'=>array('?'),
        ),
    );
}
```

When infact I believe it should be:

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('*'),
            'users'=>array('?'),
        ),
    );
}
```

Hope it helps,